# Unable to see tables in HSQLDB

Tags: spring, database, jdbc, integration-testing, hsqldb

I'm using hsql in-memory database to run my integration tests but I'm having some issues in the database. So I want to check and debug the data in the in-memory database. How can I do that??

I tried connecting with the db using sql clients but they don't show any data while debugging my integration tests.

Is there any way I can check tables?

Answer (score 0):

I suppose you are using the HSQLDB embedded in you Java application? In this case you should be able to see the data with a SQL client but only while the application is running. After application shutdown the data are lost.

When you are debugging the application not only the application will be hold on a breakpoint. The database as well. That's why you will not be able to access it during debugging. For this scenario you should rather use a standalone installation of the database.

Comment: They might also just use a thread breakpoint.